# How do i rearrange elements in a list?

Tags: java, algorithm

i have to java classes defined :

The first is :

```
 public class LinkedList {
protected LinkedListElement first;
protected LinkedListElement last;  //and so on ...
```

For context the LinkedListElement first == null all the time, and the first.nextElement is the first non null elemen. And the LinedListElement last ==

The second is :

```
public class LinkedListElement {
Object element;
LinkedListElement next;

LinkedListElement(Object obj)
{
    element = obj;
    next = null;
}

LinkedListElement(Object obj, LinkedListElement nxt)
{
    element = obj;
    next = nxt;
}}
```

They both work fine and i managed to make a function that reverses the order of elements

Now i need to write a function for the linkedList that changes the order of its' LinkedListElements in a way that changes the order from [a,b,c,d,e,f,..] to [b,a,d,c,f,e...]
and it can happen that the list is an uneven number then it changes like this: example  [a,b,c,d,e] -->  [b,a,d,c,e]
i have no idea how to even approach this without getting a can't get .next of null;
can anybody help me on how to solve this or maybe give a hint on how to approach said problem.
tnx

Comment: Hint: Try to divide the list into 2 lists like b,d,f and a,c,e etc. Now, the merging becomes easy.

Comment: Will try thank you

Answer (score 1):

As @nice_dev stated, you can split it into 2 lists and then merge them in the correct way.

Another solution would be to use a recursive approach. The method to change the order of the elements can look like this:

```java
  public void changeOrderSwapTwo() {
    
    if(first.next == null) {
      //no other elements in list: nothing to swap
      return;
    }
    //first element always has to be null, so skip this from swapping
    swapRecursive(first.next);
  }

  private void swapRecursive(LinkedListElement listElement) {
    //no next element -> nothing to swap
    if(listElement.next == null) {
      return;
    }
    // if the next element has another next element,
    // execute this method on this one too
    if(listElement.next.next != null) {
      swapRecursive(listElement.next.next);
    }

    //swapping the elements
    Object temp = listElement.next.element;
    listElement.next.element = listElement.element;
    listElement.element =temp;
  }
```

Here is the full implementation i created:

```java
public class MyLinkedList {
  protected LinkedListElement first;
  protected LinkedListElement last;

  public MyLinkedList() {
    this.first = new LinkedListElement(null);
    this.last = first;
  }

  public void add(Object o) {
    this.last.next = new LinkedListElement(o);
    this.last = this.last.next;
  }

  public void changeOrderSwapTwo() {
    if(first.next == null) {
      return;
    }
    swapRecursive(first.next);
  }

  private void swapRecursive(LinkedListElement listElement) {
    if(listElement.next == null) {
      return;
    }
    if(listElement.next.next != null) {
      swapRecursive(listElement.next.next);
    }

    Object temp = listElement.next.element;
    listElement.next.element = listElement.element;
    listElement.element =temp;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "[" + (first.next != null ? first.next : "") + "]";
  }
}
```

```java
class LinkedListElement {
  Object element;
  LinkedListElement next;

  LinkedListElement(Object obj)
  {
    element = obj;
    next = null;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return element.toString() + (next != null ? ", " + next : "");
  }
}
```

Let's do a Test:

```java
public class TestApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");
    list.add("E");

    System.out.println("Before: " + list);
    list.changeOrderSwapTwo();
    System.out.println("After: " + list);
  }
}
```

will produce the output:

```
Before: [A, B, C, D, E]
After: [B, A, D, C, E]
```